# Interesting Triangle problem

Tags: geometry

You need  to find the length of BC here.

Hello, I am preaparing for very **important** math contest. Thought that can solve geometry pretty well, but here i'm stuck.
Tried the law of sines on AMC, tried to connect M with H(obvious that BM = MC = MH) and so on.
Please show me **as much as possible** different solutions, for me to **learn** how to solve such problems.
I will be very **grateful** if someone recommend a good article or book about geometry.
Maybe vector method can be used here.

Thanks!

[image: Triangle ABC]

Comment: $\angle BMA = 3\alpha$ and $\angle MHA = \pi - 2\alpha \Rightarrow \angle AMH = \alpha$ might help. Note that this implies that $\Delta HMA$ is equilateral iff $HM = MC$ as you claimed. I don't immediately see why that would hold, though, since then $BC = 2HM = 2AH = 2$.

Comment: Thanks, how I didn't see it :))

Comment: Could you tell me how you saw $HM = MC$ so I can write up an answer?

Comment: ... and why is $\angle MHA = \pi - 2\alpha$ ?

Comment: @TomCollinge Because $\Delta CMH$ is equilateral, so $\angle CHM = \angle MCH = 2\alpha$. Then $\angle MHA = \frac\pi2 + \frac\pi2 - \angle CHM = \pi - 2\alpha$

Comment: Oh yes I can, HM is a median drawn to the hypotenuse of a right triangle CHB, there is many ways to prove it, one of them is here:http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/word/geometry/Median-in-a-right-triangle-drawn-to-its-hypotenuse.lesson

Comment: Note I scrambled the term "equilateral" with "isosceles", sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user186421 Thanks, I wrote up an answer now ;)

Comment: If you assume the result is fixed for all triangles satisfying the stated constraints, then you can "spot" that an obvious particular solution is $\alpha = \pi / 6$, making ABC equilateral. Then H is the midpoint of AB so that AB = 2 = BC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the result [$HM = MC$](http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/word/geometry/Median-in-a-right-triangle-drawn-to-its-hypotenuse.lesson) (use the theorem on $\Delta CBH$) we can see the following:

$\Delta CMH$ is isosceles, so $\angle CHM = \angle MCH = 2\alpha$. This implies
$$\angle MHA = \pi - \angle CHM = \pi - 2\alpha$$
Thus we see that $\angle AMH = \pi - \angle HMA - \angle HAM$ resulting in
$$\angle AMH = \pi - (\pi - 2\alpha) - \alpha = \alpha$$
Making $\Delta HMA$ isosceles so
$$BC = 2 MC = 2 HM = 2 AH = 2$$